# No text is returned when pypdf2 is used to scrape a one paged pdf

Tags: python, pdf-scraping

I have downloaded a bunch of pdfs from this source: 'http://ec.europa.eu/growth/tools-databases/cosing/index.cfm?fuseaction=search.detailsPDF_v2&id=28157

Now I want to scrape the PDF's by using PyPDF2, however no text is returned.

I tested the code with another pdf and it worked without a problem.

```
all_files = os.listdir('C:/Users/NAME.NAME/Downloads/Eu/T/')
count=0
count2=0
for filenames in all_files: 
   count +=1
   file_path='C:/Users/NAME.NAME/Downloads/Eu/T/'+filenames
   pdf_obj=open(file_path, 'rb')
   pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_obj)
   num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages
   current_page=0
   text2=""
   pageObj= pdf_reader.getPage(current_page)
   text2 +=pageObj.extractText()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is because PyPDF2 is a inconsistent **scraper**](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/437) . You have to remember that not all pdfs are built the same, so based on the structure that the pdf was built PyPDF2 may or may not be able to **scrape** it.

Usually when I am **scraping** pdfs, I have to switch between PyPDF2, pdfminer, and [slate3k](https://pypi.org/project/slate3k/) depending on if I get text using PyPDF2 or not. I start with PyPDF2 since it is the easiest in my opinion.

My order of robustness (how well the package can **scrape** pdfs):

1.) pdfminer

2.) slate3k

3.) PyPDF2

Using slate3k:

```
import glob as glob
all_files = r'C:/Users/NAME.NAME/Downloads/Eu/T/*.pdf'
for filenames in glob.glob(all_files): 
    with open(filenames,'rb') as f:
       pdf_text = slate.PDF(f)
       print(text)
```

Using pdfminer

```
import glob as glob
import io
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,
                                  password=password,
                                  caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text
    
all_files = r'C:/Users/NAME.NAME/Downloads/Eu/T/*.pdf'
    
for files in glob.glob(all_files):
    convert_pdf_to_txt(files)
```

You may need to change the functions to get the text in the format you want it in. As I said since PDFs can be built in so many ways your text can be outputted in numerous different ways. But this should get you in the right direction.